# ChartJS Update specific bar's background colour

Tags: chart.js

I would like to update specific column background colour but I couldn't do this. Seem like it is very easy but all the solution I tried out from google doesn't work. The code is as below.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                                        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                                            type: 'bar',
                                            data: {
                                                labels : ["A","B","C","D","E"],
                                                datasets: [{

                                                    data : [<?php echo $graph_data;?>],
                                                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,220,0.5)",
                                                    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,220,1)",

                                                    borderWidth: 2
                                                }]
                                            }
                                        });

                                        //I would like to achieve something like this, let's say change the first and second bar's background color 
                                        myChart.datasets[0].bars[0].fillColor = "rgba(220,0,0,0.5)";
                                        myChart.datasets[0].bars[1].fillColor = "rgba(220,0,0,0.5)";
                                        myChart.update();
```

I had an old code which run succesfully under version 1.0.1-beta.4, but now I world like to use the latest version 2.5.0, and then I faced this issue.

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an array to the `backgroundColor` [bar chart dataset property](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-dataset-structure) (instead of a single color) where the position in the array maps to the position in the data array.

For example, if you have 3 bars and want all 3 to be a different color, just pass an array to `backgroundColor` where all 3 elements have a different color value.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Car", "Bike", "Walking"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Fuel',
      backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.red,
        chartColors.blue,
        chartColors.yellow],
      data: [
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
        randomScalingFactor(), 
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js - Different Bar Colors"
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
  }
});
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeOXxX) demonstrating this.